# PHP fatal error uncaught exception after installing magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, centos7

I have installed magento2 in my linux centos7. After installing magento2 successfully while accessing the web page is getting following error with empty content.

```
{{menuState.title}}
```

PHP version:7.1.3
OS: centos7

And the PHP-fpm error log has following error.

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::setResponse() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract, instance of Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response given, called in /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Profiler/Driver/Standard/Output/Firebug.php on line 61 and defined in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Abstract.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Profiler/Driver/Standard/Output/Firebug.php(61): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract->setResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#1 /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Profiler/Driver/Standard.php(195): Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Output\Firebug->display(Object(Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Stat))
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard->display()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Abstract.php on line 70
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This was a Magento Bug reported ...
But it's already been ...
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7068

So, come on ...
Did you update the magento? What is the current version?

I found this information at the base of Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html

You have this option ...
The temporary fix is install symfony / yaml from dev branch and then our module:

```
              composer require symfony/yaml: dev-issue-814
```

composer require mirasvit/module-profiler

Try using / installing php7.2

See this Magento Project reference >>>
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49000/magento-2-is-there-a-profiler

Be sure to back up before the above procedures ...
Since I don't know the correct version of your current Magento, I looked for alternatives to fix.

I hope it helps you ...

Good luck! Send news about your progress ...